# Second Monitor Not Detected After Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Reinstallation with HDMI to USB-C Adapter

Tags: drivers, 22.04

I recently performed a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on my computer. Previously, Ubuntu was configured for dual boot with Windows 11, and during that time, my second monitor, connected via an HDMI to USB-C adapter, worked perfectly in Ubuntu.

Besides that, now my charging details became crazy. 5% is about 1hr and a half, it really changes randomly. Prior, now gone, MSI software has something to do with this?

However, after the fresh Ubuntu installation (currently not configured for dual boot), my second monitor is not being detected by the system. Here are the details of my setup:

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (freshly installed)
GNOME Version: 42.9
Graphics Hardware: Intel Iris Xe Graphics (driver: i915)
Ubuntu says this about graphics: Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
CPU: 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1185G7 @ 3.00GHz × 8
Adapter: HDMI to USB-C
```

The issues I'm facing include:

```
The second monitor is not recognized in the "Settings" > "Displays" section. I cannot find the "Detect Displays" option.
Running xrandr --auto in the terminal does not detect the second monitor either.
```

EDIT: I tried to boot ubuntu from usb live and when I run `xrandr` in try-mode, it shows two DP, `DP-1` and `DP-2`. I think that that is related to the fact that my laptop has two usb-c that can output video. Now, back into installed ubuntu, they are not appearing. Even though I wasn't able to send video through the adapter, I have hope on the fact that it is completely my fault and it has a fix.

I've tried the following troubleshooting steps:

- Checked physical connections and ensured that the monitor and cable are working with another device.
- Verified that the HDMI to USB-C adapter is compatible with my hardware.
- Checked the HDMI cable and tried different HDMI ports on the monitor.
- Ensured that the monitor is powered on and set to the correct input source (HDMI).
- List item

I also tried `lsusb` and it does recognize the adapter, but I can't see anything about the HDMI.

Adapter connected

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 27c6:6094 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix USB2.0 MISC
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. AX210 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 5986:116f Acer, Inc HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 017: ID 1532:0084 Razer USA, Ltd RZ01-0321 Gaming Mouse [DeathAdder V2]
Bus 003 Device 016: ID 1532:0235 Razer USA, Ltd BlackWidow Lite (2018)
Bus 003 Device 015: ID 14cd:1212 Super Top microSD card reader (SY-T18)
Bus 003 Device 014: ID 067b:2586 Prolific Technology, Inc. USB 2.0 Hub            
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f3:2d53 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Touchscreen
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Adapter disconnected

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 27c6:6094 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix USB2.0 MISC
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. AX210 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 5986:116f Acer, Inc HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f3:2d53 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Touchscreen
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

This is infinitely weird because of when Windows 11 was installed as well, the monitor worked fine.

Thank you in advance for your help. If you need any additional information, please let me know.